# Lose weight in half month

Tags: exercise, weight-loss

If we have to lose 5 to 7 kg weight in one and a half month then which exercise are more effective?

Answer (score 2):

Exercise your knife, fork and kitchen skills.

Stop eating all processed food and sugars, switch to a purely whole food diet (meat, fish, vegetables and fruit), drink only water and sleep at least 8 hours a night.

You will find a lot more weight loss success in those than you will any exercise routine.

Comment: I would personally also skip meat but that aside I agree with this answer fully. What you could do is add some light cardio (ie. walking an hour every morning) to get even greater results. All of this (trying to lose 7kg in a month) is obviously not the most healthy thing to do by the way.